# Does Apache httpd & Tomcat share same thread pool?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I wanted to understand how do httpd and Tomcat use threads. If I connect Apache httpd and Tomcat with a AJP connector (mod_jk) then will they both share same thread pool and use individual threads OR httpd will first acquire a thread and invoke the servlet container in the same thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not share anything but the word 'Apache' in their names.

Comment: So this means there are 2 threads involved in processing each request 1 for each of them and as far as I understand, httpd thread is blocked till the servlet returns a response. Is this correct?

Comment: First of all, it depends on your HTTPd setup, prefork or worker. Tomcat runs a JVM process with spawned threads. One request is handled by a thread on Tomcat side.